# Android: How to override the Compass action on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

When I tap on the default compass button in the map (the white and red button, on the top-left of the map) it rotates the map to the North, it is ok, but it sets the map tilt to 0, what I need is to override this method in order to set the tilt in 60 when the user touch this button

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

How about implementing an onCameraChangeListener? For example:

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        // check cameraPosition if bearing is north and tilt is zero
        // if true, set tilt to 60

}
```

Documentation for CameraPosition is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.html

Comment: Didn't work, it is triggered very often and is difficult to avoid an error when you have bearing = 0 and tilt = 0 for another reason, not only by clicking the compass button
Thanks anyway!

Comment: What I'm gonna do is to hide the default compass button and add a custom button, what I don't have idea now is how to rotate that button, I think that the setOnCameraChangeListener can help

Comment: @AllanRamírez did you find the solution to your problem,